# symfony (v2.8) project on server centos 6.7 with webmin

Tags: symfony, email, centos, mailer, webmin

I'm working on Symfony project on server CentOS 6, 7 which
already has email root@domain, I tried to send mail by command
Sendmail receiver@test and it works, I want to send mails from
controller by this email (root@domain)

## Note: to access to the server, I use

MobaExterm and webmin (v1,840).
I dunno from where I can get info of mail (smtp, host etc ...) to put it in

## config/parameters.yml

any help pls ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried swiftmailer ? sf doc 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html